# laravel: redirect to same controller with query parameters when cookie exists

Tags: laravel

First, here's a little background on what I'm trying to accomplish:

I'm building a SaaS app, and on the marketing site, the user can select a plan which will direct them to the registration page. I'm using a very similar flow to Mailchimp.

Once they register, they have to verify their email. Once they verify their email, they "complete" their account with information like address, city, etc.

Then, they're taken to the paywall.

**My problem**

I need a way of remembering which plan they wanted from the marketing site when they land on the paywall. To do this I was going to set a cookie.

If a cookie exists of a certain value, I want to redirect to that same route, but add a query parameter such as `?plan=free`

Here is my controller function tied to the route `route('paywall')`

```
/**
     * Returns all the data needed for the paywall
     */
    public function paywall() {

        if ($plan_intent = Cookie::get('plan-intent')) {
            return redirect()->route('paywall', ['plan' => $plan_intent]);
        }

        $account = auth()->user()->accounts->first();
        $billingAccount = $account->billingAccount;
        $contactDetails = $account->contactDetails();



        return view('account.paywall', [
            'plans' => Plan::all(),
            'intent' => $account->createSetupIntent(),
            'currentPlan' => $account->plan,
            'contactDetails' => $contactDetails,
            'billingAccount' => $billingAccount,
            'states' => State::all()
        ]);
    }
```

The code above is causing a redirection loop: `(site name) redirected you too many times.`

How can I conditionally add query parameters to the same route and redirect to the same route?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a check to see if the param was there. That's why the redirect loop was happening:

```
if ($plan_intent = Cookie::get('plan-intent') && !request()->input('plan')) {
   return redirect()->route('paywall', ['plan' => $plan_intent]);
}
```